# How to return an array / vector of unique pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector, unique-ptr

Try the following code with native array, std::array and std::vector

```
typedef unique_ptr<int> UPtr;

UPtr[] f() // wrong, how to return a native array?
{
    UPtr a[] = { UPtr(new int(1)), UPtr(new int(2)) };
    return std::move(a);
}

std::array<UPtr, 2> g()
{
    std::array<UPtr, 2> a = { UPtr(new int(1)), UPtr(new int(2)) }; // compile ok but run wrong, 1 and 2 are not assigned
    return std::move(a); // wrong, call a deleted function
}

std::vector<UPtr> h()
{
    std::vector<UPtr> a = { UPtr(new int(1)), UPtr(new int(2)) }; // wrong, call a deleted function
    return std::move(a);
}
```

All failed. There are many problems here. How to fix them? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you list the problems you encountered and for each one provide a short description of what have you tried to fix it?

Comment: I shew problems in the code

Comment: the error is not related to return array. it is about `initializer_list`.

Comment: Do not use std::move(a) in a return statement. In all your case, a is already a tempory object.

Comment: @Krozark: It's most certainly not a temporary object, as it patently has a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `std:array<T, N>` is an aggregate, it's as copyable or movable as its members permit. This means everything should work as intended. Indeed, the following code compiles fine with Clang, libc++ and `-std=c++1y` (the latter chosen for `std::make_unique`), and also in GCC 4.8 with libstdc++ if you spell out the `make_unique` calls:

```
#include <memory>
#include <array>

std::array<std::unique_ptr<int>, 2> f()
{
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<int>, 2> a = { {
        std::make_unique<int>(1), std::make_unique<int>(2) } };
    return a;
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto a = f();
    std::cout << *a[0] << " " << *a[1] << "\n";

    for (auto const & p : f())
        std::cout << *p << "\n";
}
```

Note, though, that brace elision (especially in the context of direct-list-initialization) and aggregate initialization of movable-only types are new features of C++11 for which vendor support is evolving only slowly, so that bugs are not uncommon.

Also note that list-initialization (either direct- or copy-) of a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>` cannot work, since that one would require a constructor call that takes an `std::initializer_list`, which cannot handle movable-only types. By contrast, `std::array` works because list-initialization is aggregate initialization in that case.

Comment: [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/160ed235cd44020d)

Comment: Why use 2 braces {{  }}?

Comment: @user1899020: Added. It's called "brace elision", and nobody understands it (probably not even your compiler), so I chose to keep all the braces where they belong. A good compiler (Clang) will tell you what you need to do if you forget.

Comment: I am always confused about initializations. What is the outer braces for and inner braces for? Thanks.

Comment: @user1899020: I wasn't joking. Nobody understands brace elision. There's one brace pair for each object that's itself an aggregate.